# Filter specific packages in @ComponentScan

Tags: spring, annotations

I want to switch from XML based to Java based configuration in Spring. Now we have something like this in our application context:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="foo.bar">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="o.s.s.Service"/>
</context:component-scan>
<context:component-scan base-package="foo.baz" />
```

But if I write something like this...

```
 @ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"foo.bar", "foo.baz"},
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
       value= Service.class, 
       type = FilterType.ANNOTATION
    )
 )
```

... it will exclude services from **both** packages. I have the strong feeling I'm overlooking something embarrassingly trivial, but I couldn't find a solution to limit the scope of the filter to `foo.bar`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You simply need to create two `Config` classes, for the two `@ComponentScan` annotations that you require.

So for example you would have one `Config` class for your `foo.bar` package:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo.bar"}, 
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Service.class, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION)
)
public class FooBarConfig {
}
```

and then a 2nd `Config` class for your `foo.baz` package:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo.baz"})
public class FooBazConfig {
}
```

then when instantiating the Spring context you would do the following:

```
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(FooBarConfig.class, FooBazConfig.class);
```

An alternative is that you can use the `@org.springframework.context.annotation.Import` annotation on the first `Config` class to import the 2nd `Config` class. So for example you could change `FooBarConfig` to be:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"foo.bar"}, 
    excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = Service.class, type = FilterType.ANNOTATION)
)
@Import(FooBazConfig.class)
public class FooBarConfig {
}
```

Then you would simply start your context with:

```
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(FooBarConfig.class)
```

Comment: What happens to `Service.class` ?