# String pattern for FilterType.ANNOTATION in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I'm using a Java based configuration class to develop a Spring MVC app. I want to add a filter for my *Controller* classes in `@ComponentScan` like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.fandom.configclass" }, 
excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter (type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, 
pattern = "org.springframework.stereotype.Controller")})
public class Config {         
   // some stuff
}
```

but it seems not to work and gives me an exception saying

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [org.fandom.configclass.Config]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter type not supported with String pattern: ANNOTATION
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:179)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5528)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:717)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Filter type not supported with String pattern: ANNOTATION
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.typeFiltersFor(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:178)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:107)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:229)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
    ... 19 more
```

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238089/filter-specific-packages-in-componentscan), but it is not satisfying the exclude filter on `@Controller` as defined

```
pattern = "org.springframework.stereotype.Controller")
```

How can I write a string pattern for [`FilterType.ANNOTATION`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/FilterType.html#ANNOTATION)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@ComponentScan`, or rather the `ComponentScanAnnotationParser` that processes it, does not support a `pattern` value with `FilterType.ANNOTATION`. Instead, just provide a `@ComponentScan.Filter#value` with a `Class` value of the appropriate type.

```
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = { "org.fandom.configclass" },
    excludeFilters = { 
            @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class) 
    }
)
```

---

In a comment, you state

> I want to exclude a package containing Controllers

I don't know of a way to exclude an entire package from component scanning just because it includes a single `@Controller` annotated type. However, if all you want to do is to exclude `@Controller` packages from a specified package, then the above is the way to do it.

For example

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        System.out.println(ctx.getBeansWithAnnotation(Controller.class));
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example" },
        excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class) })
class Config {
}
```

which prints

```
{}
```

an empty `Map` returned by `getBeansWithAnnotation`.