# How to include one Spring Boot application as a dependency in another

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm wondering if this is possible and/or recommended.

My use case is I have Project A that stands up on it's own and has all the core features I want. I also have Project B that is including Project A as a dependency. The basePackage of Project B is the same as Project A so it picks up Project A's configuration beans and controllers, etc... This is what I want, but I also want to be able to override configuration or extend the controllers of Project A. I cannot have multiple mappings though and that is what results, obviously. Maybe it's a matter of extending the Project A controller and excluding the extended controller.

Is this common and is there a recommended approach?

I have a feeling I'm missing something fundamental and apologize if this is basic stuff I'm new to Spring.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've found an answer for filtering packages from component scan: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238089/filter-specific-packages-in-componentscan

This gives me the ability to exclude the controllers I want to override. Still wondering if there is a concept for this type of web-app composition, but so far it's working well for my use case.

Comment: Checkout this Answer in detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/69879153/5006393

Answer (score 0):

First my core project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>br.com.rhfactor</groupId>
<artifactId>communs</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>RHFactor Communs</name>
<description>Communs entities and functions</description>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <!-- 
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
             -->
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Run following command:
`$ mvn install`

After you add to your secundary project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>br.com.rhfactor</groupId>
<artifactId>ticket</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Ticket</name>
<description>Create and manage issues</description>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- My Project --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>br.com.rhfactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>communs</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```