# Can a spring boot application class extend another dependent spring boot application class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have one spring boot project (jar) as dependent jar in another spring boot application, in the current project/application i dont want to have swagger sort of codes to be written or configured again, so is it possible to extend the spring boot application class from the dependent jar which has those configurations

Comment: You cannot use a Spring Boot generated jar as a dependency in another project, due to the different structure the classes won't be available. You would have to write a plain jar (not a spring boot application) instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it but I'd strongly recommend you *do not* do it. Spring boot applications are packaged differently to standard jars.. they're executable jars with other bits and bobs going on internally. If you plan on running the spring boot jar anywhere other than locally (eg within a container) it is likely to fail.

I'd recommend extracting out the common functionality to a shared module instead and add a dependency on the shared module to each parent module. This works well if you're using Gradle/maven.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for a concept it can be done the following way , just make sure the the version of dependency match to that of one extending it

#### Project 1

1. Creating a Simple Hello World Spring Web project "**projectone**" using Spring starter Project

```xml
    <groupId>com.harshit</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectone</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projectone</name>
```

2. @RestController with following API

```java
    @GetMapping("/one")
    public String helloworld()
    {
        return "Project One Works";
        
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/alone")
    public String checkmethod()
    {
        return "alone method also made its way into the second project";
        
    }
```

3. Build / run /install. the project on server.port=8081

   ```
   mvn clean install
   ```

#### Project 2

1. Creating another Simple Spring Web project "**projecttwo**" using Spring starter Project

```xml
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>projecttwo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projecttwo</name>
```

2. Add the previously created "**projectione**" as dependency in this project in the pom.xm of this project

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.harshit</groupId>
            <artifactId>projectone</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

3. Create a @RestController with the following api extending the Controller class of the "**projectione**"

```java
import com.harshit.controller.Controller;
@RestController
public class anothercontroller  extends Controller{
    
    
    @GetMapping("/two")
    public String hellomultiverse()
    {
        return helloworld();
        
    }
  @GetMapping("/three")
    public String multiverse()
    {
        return "threeworks";
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public String helloworld()
    {
        return "done ";
        
    }
```

4. Build / run /install. the project on server.port=9999

```
mvn clean install
```

##### Testing the Extensions

| Project | API | Reachable |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "projectone" method extended in "projecttwo" | Localhost:9999/alone | YES |
| "projectone" method extended + overridden in "projecttwo" | Localhost:9999/two | YES |
| "projecttwo" method | Locahost:9999/three | YES |
| "projectone" method extended + overridden in "projecttwo" | Localhost:9999/one | YES (Overridden output) |