# java spring handle @Configuration classes in project dependency libs

Tags: java, spring

I have a project A. This project is created to be a dependency for project B. But, in project A I have a spring @Configuration class, for junit testing, etc. When I build my jar for project A and add it as a dependency for B, B sees all my A's configuration classes, and begins complaining. So I have to comment @Configuration annotations is A, rebuild my libs and add them again, but it's not a good way. How to explain to project B's spring that it should not see @Configuration classes in project A`s lib. I think I need to deal with packages and component-scan, but how to do it properly?

Comment: Is your @Configuration in `test` or `src` folder? Anyway, you can use `excludeFilters` in `ComponentScan` annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to not scan project A's packages from project B, but this requires packages from both projects to not overlap.

If packages from both projects overlap, then you should use [`ComponentScan.excludeFilters`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#excludeFilters--). See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239076/1876620) for an example.