# How to exclude Controller classes from Component scan using Component filter?

Tags: java, spring

I have lots of controller classes in my project some annotated with @RestController and the rest annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody. The whole base package is getting component scanned in both root context Spring config class and and web app context Spring config class. I want to use Component Filters to stop controller classes being scanned when initializing the root context. I tried the following but it didn't work as expected. I still see the Controller classes being present in the root app context.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.xxx.yyy"}, excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Controller.class)})
public class RootSpringConfig {

}
```

Also tried using RestController.class and both but still no luck. I believe Controller.class alone should work as RestController is a wrapper around Controller and ResponseBody. I do have all my controller classes ending with *Controller in the class name is there a way to use regex to filter classes which ends with controller and/or make annotation filter work as expected.

Comment: Similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238089/filter-specific-packages-in-componentscan

Comment: @StanleyKirdey No it's not I am talking about two "different contexts" and the link you suggested is about scanning two different packages with different filters. It's totally different and moreover my question is about Controller classes not Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.concretepage",
     includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.concretepage.*.*Util"),
     excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = IUserService.class))
```

for more you can refer below link:

http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-component-scan-include-and-exclude-filter-example-using-javaconfig-and-xml-with-annotation-assignable-aspect-and-regex-filter-types

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `excludeFilters` with regular expressions to specify controllers that you don't want to scan:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxx.yyy",
  excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com\\.xxx\\.yyy\\.zzz.*"))  
public class RootSpringConfig {

}
```