# @ComponentScan filter unwanted test configuration classes

Tags: java, spring

I have a Test class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MyAppConfig.class}, excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(classes = {OtherTest.ConflictsWithAppTestConfig.class})})
...
public class MyAppTest { ... }
```

and an additional unrelated Test class:

```
public class OtherTest {
    @Configuration
    public static class ConflictsWithAppTestConfig { ... }
}
```

with the following directory structure:

```
src/java/com/example
    \_ MyAppConfig.java
    \_ somesubdirectory
        \_ <more spring components>
        ...

test/java/com/example
    \_ MyAppTest.java
    \_ OtherTest.java // with OtherTest.ConflictsWithAppTestConfig
```

The `@ComponentScan.Filter` allows me to stop importing the `OtherTest.ConflictsWithAppTestConfig` in `MyAppTest` when using `@ComponentScan`.

This works, however as I add more test cases under the same base, maintaining this list of excluded classes will grow with respect to other test classes under the same package with `@ComponentScan`.

**How can I setup the `@ComponentScan` filter to only include `src` directory configurations to let me import `test` configurations manually?**

i.e. fill in the blanks:

```
@ComponentScan(..., excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type=???, pattern=???)}
```

Comment: Here a solution with an exclude based on annotation :

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16239076/2971820)

And you can also look at this thread :

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan)

Comment: Don't use `@ComponentScan` like that, it is a test so you should be using `@ContextConfiguration` to explicitly specify what you want to load.

Comment: @M.Deinum maybe, but this is an integration test and there are a lot of moving parts i need included. (at least 20 so far). It would be nice to have the filter do the work instead.

Comment: I nowhere said you shouldn't use `@ComponentScan` I said you shouldn't use it like that. I would suggest to exclude `@Configuration` from being component-scanned and only scan other components and explicitly `@Import` the configuration you need on a custom `@Configuration` class for the test loaded with the `@ContextConfiguration`.